# How do I make an "inlined" parbox's top line align with its preceding text?

Tags: vertical-alignment, parbox

I have this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\rightarrow$ \parbox{6cm}{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. You've eaten pepper? Now drink juice!}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following:

[image]

I want the arrow to be aligned with "The quick brown fox", as though the parbox' first line was just continuing the outer paragraph right after the `\rightarrow`. What's the idiomatic way to do that?

Comment: Use `\parbox[t]`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Doh! Make this an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\parbox[t]` option to achieve the desired effect. There is also `[c]` (which is the default) and `[b]` options.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\rightarrow$ \parbox[t]{6cm}{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. You've eaten pepper? Now drink juice!}

\bigskip
$\rightarrow$ \parbox[c]{6cm}{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. You've eaten pepper? Now drink juice!}

\bigskip
$\rightarrow$ \parbox[b]{6cm}{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. You've eaten pepper? Now drink juice!}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `[t]` after `\parbox` and you'll get what you want.